# biblatex: backref option per entry

Tags: biblatex, back-referencing

`biblatex'` `backref` option can only be set globally by default. What I want to achieve is to turn it off and on for individual bibliographies. So that one `printbibliography` has `backref` enabled and other one does not. Is this possible?

**EDIT**

Here's a MWE. The goal would be to have `backref` enabled for the filmography viz. the second bibliography.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage[style=fiwi,]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bib.bib}
@incollection{Muller.M:2014a,
Address = {Baden-Baden},
Author = {Müller, Martin},
Booksubtitle = {Zum Staatsverständnis in den klassischen Utopien},
Booktitle = {Idealstaat oder Gedankenexperiment?},
Editor = {Schölderle, Thomas},
Pages = {287--304},
Publisher = {Nomos},
Title = {Richard Rortys \emph{Contingency, Irony, and Solidarity} (1989)},
Year = {2014}}
@movie{Kubrick.S:1964,
Address = {GB},
Author = {Kubrick, Stanley},
Shorttitle = {Dr. Strangelove},
Subtitle = {Dr. Seltsam oder Wie ich lernte, die Bombe zu lieben},
Title = {Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb},
Year = {1964}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{bib.bib}
\begin{document}
\cite{Muller.M:2014a}
\citefilm{Kubrick.S:1964}
\printbibliography[nottype=movie]
\newrefcontext[sorting=title]
\printbibliography[type=movie]
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you share a bit more about your setup and intentions? How are the bibliographies separated (different refsegments, refsections, some filter ...)? An MWE would also not go amiss, so we have something to play around, even if the question doesn't strictly need one.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying things. I already have some ideas and will definitely have a look at this later if it is not answered then already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several ways you can do this.

First of all, enable `backref=true` globally.

If you then only want `movie`s to have a backref, modify the macro accordingly.

```
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{%
  \ifboolexpr{not test {\iflistundef{pageref}} and test {\ifentrytype{movie}}}
    {\printtext[parens]{%
       \ifnumgreater{\value{pageref}}{1}
         {\bibstring{backrefpages}\ppspace}
         {\bibstring{backrefpage}\ppspace}%
       \printlist[pageref][-\value{listtotal}]{pageref}}}%
   {}}
```

Using this method the backref does not depend on the bibliography, but on the entry type (in your MWE the two coincide, maybe that is what you want in general, maybe not).

---

Alternatively, you suppress backrefs in the next bibliography with

```
\AtNextBibliography{\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{}}
\printbibliography[nottype=movie]
```

or you go the other way round and erase the `pageref` definition, but restore it for the relevant bibliography

```
\savebibmacro{pageref}
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{}

\begin{document}
\cite{Muller.M:2014a}
\citefilm{Kubrick.S:1964}

\printbibliography[nottype=movie]

\newrefcontext[sorting=title]
\AtNextBibliography{\restorebibmacro{pageref}}
\printbibliography[type=movie]
\end{document}
```

---

Unfortunately, `\printbibliography` has no other precode argument that we could use.

The following is a proof of concept that gives us pre and postcode where we can execute arbitrary code directly from `\printbibliography`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=fiwi,backref=true]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Muller.M:2014a,
Address = {Baden-Baden},
Author = {Müller, Martin},
Booksubtitle = {Zum Staatsverständnis in den klassischen Utopien},
Booktitle = {Idealstaat oder Gedankenexperiment?},
Editor = {Schölderle, Thomas},
Pages = {287--304},
Publisher = {Nomos},
Title = {Richard Rortys \emph{Contingency, Irony, and Solidarity} (1989)},
Year = {2014}}
@movie{Kubrick.S:1964,
Address = {GB},
Author = {Kubrick, Stanley},
Shorttitle = {Dr. Strangelove},
Subtitle = {Dr. Seltsam oder Wie ich lernte, die Bombe zu lieben},
Title = {Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb},
Year = {1964}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\savebibmacro{pageref}
\renewbibmacro*{pageref}{}

\makeatletter
\define@key{blx@bib1}{precode}{}
\define@key{blx@biblist1}{precode}{}
\define@key{blx@bib2}{precode}{\blx@key@precode{#1}}
\define@key{blx@biblist2}{precode}{\blx@key@precode{#1}}

\def\blx@key@precode#1{\def\blx@hook@option@precode{#1}}

\define@key{blx@bib1}{postcode}{}
\define@key{blx@biblist1}{postcode}{}
\define@key{blx@bib2}{postcode}{\blx@key@postcode{#1}}
\define@key{blx@biblist2}{postcode}{\blx@key@postcode{#1}}

\def\blx@key@postcode#1{\def\blx@hook@option@postcode{#1}}

\def\blx@bibliography{%
  \blx@langstrings
  \blx@bibheading\blx@theheading\blx@thetitle
  \blx@bibnote\blx@theprenote
  \begingroup
  \blx@bibinit
  \let\@noitemerr\@empty
  \let\blx@noitem\blx@warn@bibempty
  \ifnum\bibinitsep=\z@
    \let\blx@initsep\relax
  \fi
  \ifnum\bibnamesep=\z@
    \let\blx@namesep\relax
  \fi
  \csuse{blx@env@\blx@theenv}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibinit}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@bibinit@next}%
  \csuse{blx@hook@option@precode}% <--- this is new
  \let\blx@do\blx@bibitem
  \let\blx@done\blx@endbibliography
  \blx@listloop}

\def\blx@endbibliography{%
  \csuse{blx@hook@option@postcode}% <--- this is new
  \csuse{blx@endenv@\blx@theenv}%
  \blx@noitem
  \endgroup
  \blx@bibnote\blx@thepostnote
  \endgroup}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\cite{Muller.M:2014a}
\citefilm{Kubrick.S:1964}

\printbibliography[nottype=movie]

\newrefcontext[sorting=title]
\printbibliography[type=movie,precode={\restorebibmacro{pageref}}]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may define a new citation command (`\citenbf`) with no backref calling `\backtrackerref` in the *precode* part (derived from the original `\cite` command found in `fiwi.cbx`):

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citenbf}
  {\backtrackerfalse\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
```

Your modified example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\usepackage[style=fiwi,backref]{biblatex}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citenbf}
  {\backtrackerfalse\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:postnote}}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{Muller.M:2014a,
Address = {Baden-Baden},
Author = {Müller, Martin},
Booksubtitle = {Zum Staatsverständnis in den klassischen Utopien},
Booktitle = {Idealstaat oder Gedankenexperiment?},
Editor = {Schölderle, Thomas},
Pages = {287--304},
Publisher = {Nomos},
Title = {Richard Rortys \emph{Contingency, Irony, and Solidarity} (1989)},
Year = {2014}}
@movie{Kubrick.S:1964,
Address = {GB},
Author = {Kubrick, Stanley},
Shorttitle = {Dr. Strangelove},
Subtitle = {Dr. Seltsam oder Wie ich lernte, die Bombe zu lieben},
Title = {Dr. Strangelove or: How I Learned to Stop Worrying and Love the Bomb},
Year = {1964}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\citenbf{Muller.M:2014a}
\citefilm{Kubrick.S:1964}
\printbibliography[nottype=movie]
\newrefcontext[sorting=title]
\printbibliography[type=movie]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, but this means that I would have to decide when quoting a source wether `backref` should be enabled. I'd much prefer it if I could do this at a later point.