# Biblatex [Author.LastName, Year]

Tags: biblatex

I spent several hours researching but was not able to find a working solution.

[image: How it looks right now]

I need to have [Gadatsch, 2017] instead of [1]

I use the template of my school for it:

```
%% hgbbib.sty
%% Bibliography Setup
%% This file is part of the Hagenberg Thesis package for creating bachelors's and masters's theses
%% Author: Wilhelm Burger (wilhelm.burger@fh-hagenberg.at)
%% GitHub: https://github.com/Digital-Media/HagenbergThesis
%% File encoding: ASCII

\ProvidesPackage{hgbbib}[2018/10/14]

\usepackage{csquotes}               % recommended for biblatex

%Note: biblatex with bibtex backend is frozen at version 1.7.

\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,backend=biber,bibencoding=auto]{biblatex}
%\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authoryear, firstinits, mergedate=false, maxcitenames=3, maxbibnames=999]{biblatex}
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{
    bibwarn=true,
    sortcites=true,
    defernumbers=true,
    isbn=false,
    doi=false,
    backref=false}




%% titles of reference section + 3 categories of references:
\newcommand{\@bibtitle}{Quellenverzeichnis}
\newcommand{\@bibtitleLiteratur}{Literatur}
\newcommand{\@bibtitleAvmedia}{Audiovisuelle Medien}
\newcommand{\@bibtitleOnline}{Online-Quellen}
\newcommand{\@bibtitleSoftware}{Software}   

\ifthenelse{\equal{\hgb@MainLanguage}{english}}{%
    \renewcommand{\@bibtitle}{References}
    \renewcommand{\@bibtitleLiteratur}{Literature}
    \renewcommand{\@bibtitleAvmedia}{Audio-visual media}
    \renewcommand{\@bibtitleOnline}{Online sources} 
    \renewcommand{\@bibtitleSoftware}{Software}
}{}

%% categories for a split bibliography (order of declaration is important!)
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{literature}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{avmedia}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{software}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{online}

%% headings for the bibliography categories
\defbibheading{literature}{%
    \phantomsection%
    \section*{\@bibtitleLiteratur}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\@bibtitleLiteratur}%
}

\defbibheading{avmedia}{%
    \pagebreak[3]%
    \phantomsection%
    \section*{\@bibtitleAvmedia}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\@bibtitleAvmedia}%
}

\defbibheading{online}{%
    \pagebreak[3]%
    \phantomsection%
    \section*{\@bibtitleOnline}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\@bibtitleOnline}%
}

\defbibheading{software}{%
    \pagebreak[3]%
    \phantomsection%
    \section*{\@bibtitleSoftware}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{section}{\@bibtitleSoftware}%
}

\defbibheading{noheader}[]{}        % 'none' should be defined but isn't

%Assign a given bibliography entry to one of the defined categories.
\newcommand{\@AssignToBibCategory}[1]% argument 1: entry key 
{\ifthenelse{%
        \ifentrytype{online}\OR
        \ifentrytype{www}}
    {\addtocategory{online}{#1}}%
{\ifthenelse{%
        \ifentrytype{movie}\OR
        \ifentrytype{video}\OR
        \ifentrytype{music}\OR
        \ifentrytype{audio}\OR
        \ifentrytype{image}}
    {\addtocategory{avmedia}{#1}}%
{\ifthenelse{%
        \ifentrytype{software}\OR
        \ifentrytype{electronic}}
    {\addtocategory{software}{#1}}%
    {\addtocategory{literature}{#1}}% else (default)
}}}

%Hook provided by biblatex.
\AtEveryCitekey{\@AssignToBibCategory{\thefield{entrykey}}}

%This is only a wrapper to \addbibresource to allow the use
%of the classic bibtex-workflow in the future.
\newcommand{\AddBibFile}[1]{
    \addbibresource{#1}%
}

%See http://www.jr-x.de/publikationen/latex/tipps/zeilenumbruch.html
\newenvironment{bibhyphenation}% 
    {\hyphenpenalty=2%      (default 50)
     \tolerance=9999%           (default 200)
     \exhyphenpenalty=2%    (default 50)
     \linepenalty=1%            (default 10)
     \setlength{\emergencystretch}{3em}%
     % allow URL hyphenation at any character (definitions in biblatex.def)
     \setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{1}%
     \setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{1}%
     \setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{1}%
     \biburlsetup}%
    {}

% Currently the only public macro:
% \MakeBibliography ... creates a reference section split subsections (default)
% \MakeBibliography[nosplit] ... creates a one-piece reference section
\newcommand{\MakeBibliography}[1][]{
    % opt. arg (#1): optional argument "nosplit" to get a 1-piece bibliography
    %\clearpage
    \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{nosplit}}%
        {% create a single bibliography with all entries:
            \printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title={\@bibtitle}]
            \begin{bibhyphenation}  
            \printbibliography[heading=noheader]
            \end{bibhyphenation}
        }
        {% split the bibliography using the predefined categories:
            \printbibheading[heading=bibintoc,title={\@bibtitle}]
            \begin{bibhyphenation}
            \bibbycategory
            \end{bibhyphenation}
        }%
}

% Suppress unusual "In:" within journal article references. 
% see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10682/suppress-in-biblatex
\renewbibmacro{in:}{%
    \ifentrytype{article}{}{%
    \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}


% To suppress warnings related to missing biblatex "drivers":
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{video}{misc}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{movie}{misc}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{audio}{misc}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{software}{misc}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{electronic}{misc}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{image}{misc}
\DeclareBibliographyAlias{standard}{misc}


% Use a semicolon between multiple entries in \cites
\renewcommand*{\multicitedelim}{\addsemicolon\space}

% Macro to produce cites with no backref entries
% Modified from http://mirrors.ibiblio.org/CTAN/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ieee/ieee.cbx
% See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/344861/biblatex-backref-option-per-entry
\DeclareCiteCommand{\citenobr}%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \bibopenbracket
     \backtrackerfalse\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}%
   \bibclosebracket
  }
```

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add an short compilable TeX code showing how you build your bibliography and add at last one used bib entry to your question!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`biblatex-ext`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-ext) and combine `authoryear` citations with an `authortitle` bibliography and `introcite=label`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
  citestyle=ext-authoryear, bibstyle=ext-authortitle, sorting=nyt, 
  introcite=label, dashed=false,
  autocite=inline,
  articlein=false,
  isbn=false, doi=false]{biblatex}

\DeclareOuterCiteDelims{parencite}{\bibopenbracket}{\bibclosebracket}
\DeclareFieldFormat{bbx@introcite}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\itemsep}

\DeclareDelimFormat{nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\space}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\autocite{sigfridsson,worman,nussbaum,geer}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Citations and bibliography examples]

Comment: Thank you very much! this worked like a charm

Comment: @David Glad it works. If the answer solved your issue, you may want to consider accepting it: https://tex.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers